# Azure Automation Powershell DNS issue

Tags: azure, automation, azure-web-app-service

I have a much larger script but trying to diagnose why the dns lookups I am trying to do via Resolve-DnsName are blank. I tried running the basic command

```
`Resolve-DnsName -Name www.bing.com -Type CNAME`
```

Output>
[www.bing.com](http://www.bing.com) : Not enough storage is available to complete this operation

I can run this locally and get the output

Name                           Type   TTL   Section    NameHost

---

[www.bing.com](http://www.bing.com)                   CNAME  7369  Answer     www-www.bing.com.trafficmanager.net

Is the something I am missing with having to allocate storage to run azure automation?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/persisting-shell-storage#how-cloud-shell-storage-works

Comment: Azure Cloud Shell uses a persistent storage, like a storage account attached.

Comment: @sleepyhead, I am not entirely sure why it should be necessary to attach a storage on an Automation Account just to run a simple DNS lookup. I run quite sophisticated scripts without any problems, it's just a DNS lookup, which is a basic functionality that most probably is being carried out whenever accessing a URL from a runbook. Personally, I believe this error message is misleading but I haven't found the root cause. Dale: Did you happen to find a solution?

Comment: I misread the automation account and mistook it for a cloud shell. cloud shell runs with attached storage. The automation account however also throws errors ResourceUnavailable and ERROR_OUTOFMEMORY, which adds to the confusion. The real problem is that automation runs in limited sandbox without a full network stack.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules
...full stack network operations are not supported in the sandbox, including ... Resolve-DnsName ... recommended workaround is to deploy a Hybrid Runbook Worker or use Azure Functions.